# Position Aboslute queda debajo de position relative

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tengo un problema con un meno con posicion absoluta funciona todo bien pero a la hora de desplegarlo en componentes de tipo 'col, col-md-2, col-4, etc' de bootstrap, este menu queda debajo de dicho componentes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al analizar el css, veo que tienen 'position: relative;', al desactivar el position funciona correctamente, pero quisiera saber si no existe otra forma, ya que no me es factible tener que quitar la posicion relativa a todos esos componentes.

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega el código pertinente como texto.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba usar la propiedad css "z-index:9999;" en el menu.

Por ejemplo:

```
#menu{
    z-index:9999;
}
```

Esta propiedad asigna la posicion de los componentes desde el punto de vista 3d, los componentes que tengan mayor valor en el z-index saldran por encima de los demas.

Saludos.